# Importing _mysql in MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, c

Why is _mysql in the MySQLdb module a C file? When the module tries to import it, I get an import error. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It's the adaptor that sits between the Python `MySQLdb` module and the C `libmysqlclient` library. One of the most common reasons for it not loading is that the appropriate libmysqlclient library is not in place.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171078/no-module-names-mysql-where-is-mysql) might be the answer to your question.

When I try to import `_mysql`, I get no error:

```
import _mysql
print(_mysql)
# <module '_mysql' from '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/_mysql.so'>
```

It is importing the library /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/_mysql.so

If this is not what you are getting, it sounds like an installation error.
What OS are you using?
How did you install mysqldb?

Comment: I'm using XP. I think I should try downloading and installing the module again. How should I go about that?