# no module names _mysql; where is _mysql

Tags: python, mysql

```
import MySQLdb
```

and

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\zjm_code\sphinx_test\a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "D:\zjm_code\sphinx_test\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: No module named _mysql
```

Comment: You should edit the title of the question so that it makes sense. "Model names"? What does "model names" have to do with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install MySQLdb correctly. It consists of the python module and platform-dependent library (`_mysql.dll` in your case). Use the win32 installer from the project page instead of installing just by unpacking sources.